# MERGE INTO not working with Postgres 9.6

Tags: sql-merge, postgresql-9.6

In my Postgres 9.6 environment, when I try to execute "MERGE INTO" query, it throws me following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "MERGE"
LINE 1: MERGE INTO Stock USING Buy ON Stock.item_id = Buy.item_id  W...
        ^
```

It seems like it does not support MERGE query. However when I do google, it seems that MERGE is supported by Postgres since version 9.1.

Please tell me whats going wrong here.

Edit: Following are the sources from where I found MERGE support in Postgres.

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/MergeTestExamples

Comment: From the link you posted: **This was never integrated into PostgreSQL, and requires significant work to be production quality**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to UPSERT (MERGE, INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE) in PostgreSQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267417/how-to-upsert-merge-insert-on-duplicate-update-in-postgresql)

Comment: The only authoritative source for the existence or syntax of a statement is the [**the manual**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/index.html) not some random googling or a wiki page that clearly states that the functionality has not bee integrated into Postgres

Answer (score 0):

Postgres does not support the MERGE feature.

See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/unsupported-features-sql-standard.html

> F312 | MERGE statement | consider INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE

Also in the latest version (currently 14) it is not supported.

Comment: It will be included in the upcoming [version15](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/sql-merge.html)

Answer (score -4):

`MERGE` aka `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING/UPDATE` or `UPSERT` is only available to [postgres 9.5](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SQL_MERGE) and later:

> Note: MERGE is often used interchangeably with the term UPSERT.
>
> UPSERT functionality will be in the PostgreSQL 9.5 release -- see
>   What's new in PostgreSQL 9.5  MERGE is not in 9.4.5 (the latest
>   PostgreSQL release as of 2015-10-08)

Comment: The OP stated that it was not working on PostgreSQL 9.6.  Granted, it didn't work in 9.1, but that isn't the issue.